# Can we use this service for WordPress theme development?

Tags: images, copyright

I need to know if I can use the `lorempixel.com` service for WordPress theme development for commercial use considering that this service is released under the [creative commons license (CC BY-SA)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, this question will result in primarily opinion-based answers, and it's also not about a [website under your control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is off-topic on this site. You could however ask for feedback in the chat room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their service is not under that licence, since it works by hotlinking to images and so you don't actually host anything of theirs on your site.  The images they are using fall under that licence, however, which is why they credit them when they use them on their own website (since they are re-hosting the images and so have to abide by the rules)

They say, of the licence, "So, if you want to use the images for more than just layouts, you have to double check the license and ask the author."

My feeling is this means you only need to credit the author should you be planning to host the images on your own site, rather than hotlinking via Lorempixel.